# ubuntu terminal - edit file of which I'am not the owner of

Tags: file, ubuntu, edit

I'm using `ettercap`. I have instructions to change the content of the file: `etter.conf`. I can't change the file since it's read only, I also can't change its permissions since I am not the owner of the file.
Is there a way I can edit the file's content?

Comment: You could use `sudo` to edit the file, like: `sudo vi etter.conf`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can not edit a file, if you don't have the required permissions.
However, you can use `sudo`, if you need **root** access to edit file.
If that does not work, then you can use other way, prescribed by software vendors.
Just use `cp etter.conf etter-new.conf`, to copy the file and then use the new one.
Don't forget to `backup` the old one.